# How do I get a file name from a full path with PHP?

Tags: php, filenames

For example, how do I get `Output.map`

**from**

`F:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell\Output.map`

with PHP?

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You're looking for [`basename`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

The example from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
?>
```

Comment: basename() has a bug when processes Asian characters like Chinese.

Comment: Thanks Sun, you just saved me hours of bug killing since my app will be used overseas.

Comment: I would suggest `pathinfo` over `basename` as Metafaniel posted below. `pathinfo()` will give you an array with the parts of the path. Or for the case here, you can just specifically ask for the filename. So `pathinfo('/var/www/html/index.php', PATHINFO_FILENAME)` should return `'index.php'` 
[PHP Pathinfo documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: @OnethingSimple Check the docs again... counter intuitive though it is, you'll want `PATHINFO_BASENAME` to get the full `index.php`. `PATHINFO_FILENAME` will give you `index`.

Comment: in any case, for a unicode compatible method,  `mb_substr($filepath,mb_strrpos($filepath,'/',0,'UTF-16LE'),NULL,'UTF-16LE')` - just replace UTF-16LE with whatever characterset your filesystem uses (NTFS and ExFAT uses UTF16)

Comment: Caution
basename() is locale aware, so for it to see the correct basename with multibyte character paths, the matching locale must be set using the setlocale() function.

Answer (score 90):

I've done this using the function `PATHINFO` which creates an array with the parts of the path for you to use! For example, you can do this:

```
<?php
    $xmlFile = pathinfo('/usr/admin/config/test.xml');

    function filePathParts($arg1) {
        echo $arg1['dirname'], "\n";
        echo $arg1['basename'], "\n";
        echo $arg1['extension'], "\n";
        echo $arg1['filename'], "\n";
    }

    filePathParts($xmlFile);
?>
```

This will return:

```
/usr/admin/config
test.xml
xml
test
```

The use of this function has been available since PHP 5.2.0!

Then you can manipulate all the parts as you need. For example, to use the full path, you can do this:

```
$fullPath = $xmlFile['dirname'] . '/' . $xmlFile['basename'];
```

Comment: I had to change `\n` into `<br>` to get the formatted output you're describing?

Comment: @FrankConijn Because of your question, I can see you're using a web browser with my code snippet. In that case: yes, you have to replace `\n` with `<br>`. My code is meant to be run using the command line, thus the line breaks with `\n` work. Greetings.

Answer (score 19):

There are several ways to get the file name and extension. You can use the following one which is easy to use.

```
$url = 'http://www.nepaltraveldoor.com/images/trekking/nepal/annapurna-region/Annapurna-region-trekking.jpg';
$file = file_get_contents($url); // To get file
$name = basename($url); // To get file name
$ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // To get extension
$name2 =pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // File name without extension
```

Answer (score 15):

With **SplFileInfo**:

> SplFileInfo The SplFileInfo class offers a high-level object oriented
>   interface to information for an individual file.

**Ref**: http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/foo.txt');
var_dump($info->getFilename());
```

> o/p: string(7) "foo.txt"

Answer (score 14):

The [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) function should give you what you want:

> Given a string containing a path to a
>   file, this function will return the
>   base name of the file.

For instance, quoting the manual's page:

```
<?php
    $path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
    $file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
    $file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
?>
```

Or, in your case:

```
$full = 'F:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell\Output.map';
var_dump(basename($full));
```

You'll get:

```
string(10) "Output.map"
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php')
```

Answer (score 9):

basename() has a bug when processing Asian characters like Chinese.

I use this:

```
function get_basename($filename)
{
    return preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $filename);
}
```

Comment: I don't think its a bug, in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) its mentioned: `Caution

basename() is locale aware, so for it to see the correct basename with multibyte character paths, the matching locale must be set using the setlocale() function.
`. But I also prefere to use preg_replace, because the directory separator differ between operating systems. On Ubuntu `\\` is not a directoy separator and basename will have no effect on it.

Answer (score 8):

```
$filename = basename($path);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in the fewest lines I would suggest using the built-in `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant  along with `explode(delimiter, string)` to separate the path into parts and then simply pluck off the last element in the provided array.

Example:

```
$path = 'F:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH SecureShell\Output.map'

//Get filename from path
$pathArr = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
$filename = end($pathArr);

echo $filename;
>> 'Output.map'
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the exact file name from the URI, I would use this method:

```
<?php
    $file1 =basename("http://localhost/eFEIS/agency_application_form.php?formid=1&task=edit") ;

    //basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // Or use this to get the URI dynamically.

    echo $basename = substr($file1, 0, strpos($file1, '?'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. For example:

```
<?php
    function filePath($filePath)
    {
        $fileParts = pathinfo($filePath);

        if (!isset($fileParts['filename']))
        {
            $fileParts['filename'] = substr($fileParts['basename'], 0, strrpos($fileParts['basename'], '.'));
        }
        return $fileParts;
    }

    $filePath = filePath('/www/htdocs/index.html');
    print_r($filePath);
?>
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => /www/htdocs
    [basename] => index.html
    [extension] => html
    [filename] => index
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$image_path = "F:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell\Output.map";
$arr = explode('\\',$image_path);
$name = end($arr);
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $windows = "F:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell\Output.map";

  /* str_replace(find, replace, string, count) */
  $unix    = str_replace("\\", "/", $windows);

  print_r(pathinfo($unix, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

?>
```

```css
body, html, iframe { 
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ideone.com/Rfxd0P"></iframe>
```