# PHP Extract only the Filename from UNC Path

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an Intranet page that looks up all pdf documents in a UNC path and the returns them in a list as hyperlinks that opens in a new window. I'm nearly there however the following code displays the FULL UNC path - My question how can I display only the Filename (preferably without the .pdf extension too). I've experimented with the *basename* function but can't seem to get the right result.

```
//path to Network Share
$uncpath = "//myserver/adirectory/personnel/";
//get all files with a .pdf extension.
$files = glob($uncpath . "*.pdf");
//print each file name
foreach ($files as $file) 
{
echo "<a target=_blank href='File:///$file'>$file</a><br>"; 
}
```

The links work fine it just the display text shows `//myserver/adirectory/personnel/document.pdf` rather than just `document`. Note the above code was taken from another example I found whilst researching. If there's a whole new better way then I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You are looking for [`basename`](http://php.net/basename).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
<?
$uncpath = "//myserver/adirectory/personnel/";
//get all files with a .pdf extension.
$files = glob($uncpath . "*.pdf");
//print each file name
foreach ($files as $file) 
{
echo "<a target=_blank href='File:///$file'>".basename($file)."</a><br>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: To remove extension :
echo "<a target=_blank href='File:///$file'>".preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "",basename($file))."</a><br>";

Answer (score 4):

```
echo basename($file);
```

http://php.net/basename

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, if basename() does not work for some reason:

```
$file_a = explode('/',$file);
if (trim(end($file_a)) == '')
    $filename = $file_a[count($file_a)-2];
else
    $filename = end($file_a);
```