# Is there any way to get a filename from a full path?

Tags: php, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

File Path :

```
users_gallery/2012/August/14-August-2012/8/Sasasas/b_80.27016000 134489509114 08 2012kites-4v.jpg
```

I there any way to take out the file name:

```
b_80.27016000 134489509114 08 2012kites-4v.jpg
```

Comment: [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: yes already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php/30995028#30995028

Answer (score 0):

Use php basename funcion http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = explode('/', 'users_gallery/2012/August/14-August-2012/8/Sasasas/b_80.27016000 134489509114 08 2012kites-4v.jpg');
$file = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
echo $file;
```

This should echo `b_80.27016000 134489509114 08 2012kites-4v.jpg`