# Get URL from server path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading a file using Codeigniter's File Uploading Library and trying to insert the URL into the database. Codeigniter only supplies the server_path when using `$this->upload->data()`, which isn't usable for displaying the image to users.

I could normally just do something like `base_url('uploads) . '/' . $data['file_name']` but I am storing the images in a folder for each post.

For example, I am getting `C:/xampp/htdocs/site/uploads/32/image.jpg` as the full_path, how can I convert this to `http://mysite.com/uploads/32/image.jpg`

The only thing that comes to mind is using a regular expression, but I feel like there has to be PHP function or Codeigniter function to help with this?

How can I convert the server path into the correct URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; to get the url. Using the ID for your post, you can construct your path like so:

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $id . "/" . basename($data['file_name']);
```

the basename() function returns everything after the last / in your path.

Answer (score 0):

In `CodeIgniter` you should use `$config['base_url']`

You can use the `ENVIRONMENT` to setup different `base_url`, for example:

```
switch(ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
        break;
    case 'testing':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://testing.server.com/';
        break;
    default:
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://liveserver.com/';    
}
```

See `config.php`

Now simply replace your local path with the `base_url`, `str_replace` should do the job (documentation [here](https://www.php.net/str_replace))

```
$newpath = str_replace("C:/xampp/htdocs/site/", $config['base_url'], $localpath);
```

Also, if you're interested in getting parts of the path, you could use `explode` (documented [here](https://www.php.net/explode)) with `/` to create an array with every "section" of your path

```
$pathElements = explode('/', $localpath);
```

In this case, `$pathElements[0]` is `C:`, `$pathElements[1]` is `xampp`, etc...

Comment: You should look into the `Environments` section on the [Config Class Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html) which seems like a more pratcial solution to what you are trying achieve. The environment is specified in `index.php`

Comment: @Malachi that's what I use for database settings but for a simple base_url I prefer keeping everything in the same file

Answer (score 0):

you only need to save the filename to the database and just use the post id and filename:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/uploads/" . $postID . "/" . $fileName;
```

to get the file name use: [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

```
<?php
$path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/site/uploads/32/image.jpg";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "image.jpg"
$file = basename($path, ".jpg"); // $file is set to "image"
?>
```