# Get URL of a file on a server with PHP

Tags: php, url, path, getcwd

Say I want to find a file in one of the parent directories of the script. Consider this file tree:

```
Folder0
    Folder1
        needle.php
        Folder2
            Folder3
                script.php
```

I'm running `script.php` and I need to find which directory contains `needle.php`. I do this:

```
while (!file_exists($nameFile)) {
    chdir('..');
    }
return getcwd();
```

This returns "Folder0\Folder1\";

**What is the proper way to transform this path into a URL of this file?** (e.g. `` `http://hostname.com/Folder0/Folder1/needle.php" ``)

Or is there **a better way to get a URL of a file on a server?**

Comment: Use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

Comment: Found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13616247/710356. Is it solid?

Answer (score 6):

```
getcwd()
```

give You current dir from server root like **/home/vincent/public_html/folder** You Can get DOCUMENT_ROOT By

```
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];//  /home/vincent/public_html
```

You Must Remove DOCUMENT_ROOT from first of getcwd and concat with Host Name. like this

```
  echo str_replace("\\",'/',"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr(getcwd(),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));
```

output:

```
 http://www.domain.com/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

and here is a good [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-do-i-recursively-scan-directories-with-phps-directoryiterators/417) that might help you

I hope this help,  if anymore help needed we are here and glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!file_exists($nameFile)) {
    chdir('..');
}
return "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('\\', '/', getcwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

> $basePath="http://hostname.com/"; $fileName="needle.php";
>   $folderPath="Folder0\Folder1\";
>
> $path=str_replace("\","/",$folderPath);
>   $pathToFile=$basePath.$path.$fileName;
>
> echo $pathToFile;

Make a function out of it !

Lucian