# How to get dir name from full path with PHP?

Tags: php, filenames, relative-path

I have a image path like this..

```
2012/12/14/example.jpg
```

Now I would like to get the path except image name..

I mean I need like this

```
2012/12/14/
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/dirname - Related: [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('2012/12/14/example.jpg');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; 
?>
```

output will be..

```
   /www/htdocs/inc
    example.jpg
    jpg
    example
```