# How to remove directory string from a file name

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td width="11%" class="videotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrVideoFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrVideoFile[$key]) : $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ). '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td width="11%" class="audiotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrAudioFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrAudioFile[$key]) : $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ). '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

In the above code I have 2 table columns which depending if there are content or not display information in the table cells. Now as you can see the three columns are `Image`, `Video` and `Audio`. Now these columns display the relevant file names in their table cells. Below is how they are displayed:

- All Image Files contain the string `ImageFiles/` before the filename, e.g. `ImageFiles/Lighthouse.png`
- All Video Files contain the string `VideoFiles/` before the filename, e.g. `VideoFiles/sample_mpeg.mp4`
- All Audio Files contain the string `AudioFiles/` before the filename, e.g. `AudioFiles/Music.mp3`

As you can see each file contains the directory string before the filename. But what I want to do is that for each column and for each file, remove the relative directory string or in other words remove `ImageFiles/`, `AudioFiles/` and `VideoFiles/` from the whole string of each filename as I do not want the user to know the name of the directory. But how can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has a function for it: [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename)

Comment: Best answer as you just pipped the other answer which was similar

Answer (score 5):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename)

```
echo basename($arrImageFile[$key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the last index of / and do a substring to extract everything after it.