# Get only the filename from a path

Tags: php, string, filenames

I have this string

```
$string = 'C:\Folder\Sub-Folder\file.ext';
```

I want to change it to:

```
$string = 'file.ext';
```

Using PHP, I am trying to write a method that ignores everything left of the last `\`.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php

Answer (score 8):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) with `str_replace()` as the `\` in the path [is not recognized by `basename()`](https://eval.in/375708)

```
$filename = basename(str_replace('\\', '/', 'C:\Folder\Sub-Foler\file.ext'));
echo $filename; // file.ext
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/375707)

Comment: To be correct here, it does recognize the backslash, but only on windows :) As I would say it RTM xD

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is this:

Split the string by a delimiter(`\`) to form an array: `['C:', 'Folder', 'Sub-Foler', 'file.ext']` using `explode`: `explode("\\", $string);`

Get the last element in the array using the `end` function, which you want as the result.

Put it all together:

```
$string = 'C:\Folder\Sub-Foler\file.ext';
$stringPieces = explode("\\", $string);
$string = end($stringPieces);
```

Here's a demo: http://3v4l.org/i1du4