# Can I upload a file using PHP if I ONLY have the absolute path?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What if I have no way of getting the input file:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
```

After choosing the file I want to upload, the input field will disappear.
Instead, it will display the absolute path:

```
C:\users\foo\Desktop\file.zip
C:\fakepath\file.zip
```

Here's the code I used to get the absolute path:

```
<script>
$('#upload').on('change',function(){

var filename = document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "execs/upload.php",
    data: { filename: filename},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert ("Success")
    },

    error: function () {
        alert ("Failed")
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

Will I still be able to upload it in PHP? Most of what I get online is that I will need $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']. I don't know how I'll get it if I only have the absolute path.

This is the upload.php file:

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST["filename"];  //C:\users\foo\Desktop\file.zip
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;

if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $target_file)){  // $target_file = uploads/file.zip
echo "yes";
} 
else echo "no";
?>
```

When I also checked if the file exists ($filename), it says it does NOT.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "Instead I can only get the absolute path" ? You want to put a path in a text input and upload a file?

Comment: hello @DamienPirsy.. yes, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$_POST[]` for a file input, use `$_FILES[]` instead.

For more information check this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post:
[How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

There are two methods:

1. Using pathinfo.
2. Using basename.

I prefere pathinfo more.

```
    <?php
$xmlFile = pathinfo('/usr/admin/config/test.xml');

function filePathParts($arg1) {
echo $arg1['dirname'], "\n";
echo $arg1['basename'], "\n";
echo $arg1['extension'], "\n";
echo $arg1['filename'], "\n";
}

filePathParts($xmlFile);
?>
```

This will return:

/usr/admin/config

test.xml

xml

test

```
<?php
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_POST` use `$_FILES` as

```
$filename = $_FILES["upload"];
print_r($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
            $uploaddir = "/www/uploads/";
           $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);

   echo '<pre>';
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
         echo "Success.\n";
   } else {
         echo "Failure.\n";
   }

  echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
  print_r($_FILES);
  print "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have `$filename = $_POST["filename"];` but change that to:

```
$filename = $_POST["upload"];
```

Since you have:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">

So: name="upload"
```

Comment: Files are in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.