# Get String After a Certain Character While Avoiding UTF-8 Bugs

Tags: php, utf-8

I have done my research before posting, but cannot find an answer to this. How do I get the portion of a string after a certain character?

For example, for the string:

```
gallery/user/profile/img_904.jpg
```

I want to return:

```
img_904.jpg
```

I am also concerned about bugs with `basename()` regarding UTF-8 filenames containing Asian characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php

Comment: Which character? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `gallery/user/profile/img_904.jpg ` is the path. I want to return `img_904.jpg `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can just use the [`basename()` function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
php > $path = 'gallery/user/profile/img_904.jpg';
php > echo basename($path);
img_904.jpg
```

As a more general example, if you wanted to get the part of a string after the last `|`, for example, you could use an approach like this:

```
php > $string = 'Field 1|Field 2|Field 3';
php > echo substr(strrchr($string, '|'), 1);
Field 3
```

Or even:

```
php > $string = 'Field 1|Field 2|Field 3';
php > echo substr($string, strrpos($string, '|') + 1);
Field 3
```

**Edit**

You noted problems with UTF-8 handling in `basename()`, which is a problem I have run into as well with several versions of PHP. I use the following code as a workaround on UTF-8 paths:

```
/**
 * Returns only the file component of a path. This is needed due to a bug
 * in basename()'s handling of UTF-8.
 *
 * @param string $path Full path to to file.
 * @return string Basename of file.
 */
function getBasename($path)
{
    $parts = explode('/', $path);

    return end($parts);
}
```

From the [PHP `basename()` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

> **Note:**
>   basename() is locale aware, so for it to see the correct basename with multibyte character paths, the matching locale must be set using the setlocale() function.

Comment: Is `basename()` bug fixed? Processing Asian characters?

Comment: Ah, didn't know we were dealing with UTF-8. See my edit; I added a working example for that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$path = 'gallery/user/profile/img_904.jpg';
$filename = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
echo $filename; 


?>
```

This will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = gallery/user/profile/img_904.jpg;
$temp = explode('/', $path);
$filename = $temp[count($temp)-1];
```