# Grabbing data from SQL column and splitting it to populate function

Tags: php, split, setter

If I grab data from a column in my database called `image_store` such as:

```
/web/images/data/firstImage.png
/web/images/data/secondImage.png
/web/images/data/thirdImage.png
```

And I want to populate a setImage function which takes the string after `/data/` to set as the fileName and the string before `/firstImage.png` as the directory e.g:

```
$this->setImage('firstImage.png', '/web/images/data/')
```

Is there a way I can grab the needed information from the string I get back from the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply use `explode/implode` functions and `array_pop()` to take image name itself:

```
<?php
    $sqlArr = array('/web/images/data/firstImage.png', '/web/images/data/secondImage.png', '/web/images/data/thirdImage.png');
    foreach($sqlArr as $fullPath){
        $tmp = explode('/', $fullPath);
        $imgName = array_pop($tmp);
        $imgPath = implode('/', $tmp).'/';
        $this->setImage($imgName, $imgPath);
    }
?>
```

This will works with any depth of url paths.