# Cut letters from behind with substr

Tags: php, substr

```
<?php echo $entry->field('logo')->generate(); ?>
```

This gives me the path of my images, but I want to cut the last 3 letters from the back(the suffix).

The normal function is:

```
<?php
rest = substr("Test", 0, -1);
?>
```

But I don't get an output with this:

```
<?php
$rest = substr($entry->field('logo')->generate(), 0, -1); 
?>
```

Comment: i think u cut the extension of your image ?

Comment: Add the response of this line:  echo $entry->field('logo')->generate();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the `value` in a variable

```
$var = $entry->field('logo')->generate();
```

Then you put the `substr` function on the `variable`

```
$rest = substr($var, 0, -1);
```

Comment: No problemo friend.Anytime

Comment: I've got another question, my image path looks like this:  assets/images/b/logo.png. is it possible to cut the path to the third "/" so that I only got the filesname?

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp to do what you exactly want to do with your data

Comment: The problem is, that the path of the files is not always 10 characters long.

Comment: For your problem can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php