# Get only the filename with certain extension in a folder - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, glob

I'm trying to get only the filename of the path using PHP code. I have used glob() function but its returning me this result:

**C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CSVFiles\672VER.csvC:\Users\HP\Desktop\CSVFiles\ACC1.csvC:\Users\HP\Desktop\CSVFiles\EMP.csv**

I only want to get **672VER, ACC1 and EMP**

Anyone can help me in doing this? :( I was up until morning just trying to figure out this code.

Here's my code

```
$files = array();
foreach (glob("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CSVFiles\*.csv") as $file1) {
  $files[] = $file1;

  echo $file1;

}
```

Update:
I went to this link [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)  and it didnt get me the result I want....
It only gave me an asterisk(*) sign...

Comment: I went to the link and my Path has a wild card on it..  
"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CSVFiles\*.csv" 
However, I'm only getting an asterisk(*) sign
I want to get all files that has a filename extension .csv

Comment: nvm.. I got it.. THANKS!