# PHP trouble getting symlinked "file name" without full path

Tags: php, symlink

I am wondering if this is at all possible.  There are lots of questions on the subject in SO, but none address this specific issue.

I have a symlink that looks like this:

```
reroof-for-abe-froman.php -> /var/www/yourprojects/app/project.php
```

Now all I want returned from a variable is `reroof-for-abe-froman` with, or without the extension (preferably without).

I have tried all of these:

```
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php') . "\n";
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\n";
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "\n";
echo __FILE__ . "\n";
```

With the following results:

> project
>   /project/reroof-for-abe-froman
>   /var/www/liveSites/websites/allseasonsny/public_html/project/reroof-for-abe-froman.php
>   /var/www/yourprojects/app/project.php

Now I realize I can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `str_replace` or `explode` to get what I want. IE:

```
$uri = str_replace('/project/', '',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Which would give the desired output.  I was just wondering if there was a "cleaner" way to accomplish this without the manipulation of a `_SERVER` variable?

Comment: `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-do-i-get-a-file-name-from-a-full-path-with-php

Comment: @NigelRen I never thought to combine `basename` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  --  I thought it would do the same thing as `basename(__FILE__, '.php')` because in the documentation it implies that it would return the original path .. Why does this work?  Write in an answer and I'll accept.