# How to separate the extension from a file?

Tags: php

I need to encode a file before i include it to the bank with the code below:

```
    $file = 'CT0001_0002.1.jpg';
    $validate = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    list($name,$extension) = explode($validate,$file);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    $cod = md5($name.$date).".".$extension;
    echo $cod;
```

When I print, it returns like this:

```
6ab87875286005866f0504961fc2438c.
```

Without the extension. Pathinfo() is enabled on the server. He should return:

```
6ab87875286005866f0504961fc2438c.jpg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a file name from a full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-do-i-get-a-file-name-from-a-full-path-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) already provides all the details you'd need:

```
<?php

$file = 'CT0001_0002.1.jpg';
$validate = pathinfo($file);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i");

$cod = md5($validate['filename'] . $date) . "." . $validate['extension'];
echo $cod;
```

`print_r($validate)` would output:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => .
    [basename] => CT0001_0002.1.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => CT0001_0002.1
)
```