# R project: regex: keep everything after a character

Tags: r, regex

I work with R programing language.
I have a data frame with one column contains url like this:

```
myUrl <- "https://twitter.com/UserName"
```

I need to get rid of **everything before the last /**. The regex pattern seems to be (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150559/regular-expression-to-collect-everything-after-the-last))

`[^/]+$`

I can't find the correct function to keep **UserName**. I thought grep was my friend, but it does not work:

```
[R] grep('[^/]+$', myUrl)
[1] 1
```

Obviously this is not what I want. No success with other family functions.
Can someone please tell me the correct command?

Comment: `gsub('/U.*',"\\1", myUrl)`
`gsub('.*/',"\\1", myUrl)`
The U is the fisrt character of your username

Comment: @OrhanYazar  thank you. Second answer is the one I need.

Comment: np ;) fell free to use it